# Word describing a self-indulgent, moralizing, but ultimately phony/nonsensical attitude

Tags: word-choice

I'm probably going to turn people away with this example, but this is what I'm thinking of, so here goes:

Imagine a meeting at a university. Several well-paid university administrators gather around a table with a collection of student leaders who have been pushing for more "inclusion". The student president stands up perfectly erect and says self-assuredly, "We are well aware of the systematic emotional violence enacted against students of color. We see it every day. One is well aware of the trauma they feel. One is well aware of the dispossession they feel. One is well aware of the tears that have fallen resulting from this violence. As a student of color, I have felt this pain in my own life. I *know* how it feels to be oppressed... And though much has been done, there is still much more to do because, like the serpents that swing down from the trees, so too does white supremacy so often rear its ugly head. We must fight racism, inequality, and injustice no matter where we stand. We must fight privilege no matter who we are."

After her triumphant speech, the doe-eyed administrators nod in unison, seemingly amazed by her cliched remarks. And the student-body president who had spent all day in meetings hosted by a university "system" that was "hostile" to her, sat down with a look of satisfaction.

---

So what word would describe the participants in this meeting? What word would describe the situation or atmosphere?

Corporate board meetings have a similar feeling, if that's an experience you're familiar with. Especially when bureaucrats take turns telling each other how much good their company does for the world, each person inflating the ego of each other as he speaks.

It's like the atmosphere is a bubble waiting to be pricked by someone a bit brash. The language used by the student president is so over-the-top so as to be almost laughable. Maybe "sanctimonious" describes it? Having your "head up your ass" seems like the colloquial phrase for it.

Comment: Can you clarify who you’re talking about?  Your title suggests it’s the student president.  But the question in the body asks about the participants.

Comment: I’ve heard it called *motherhood and apple pie*

Comment: I see no reason to close this question. It is clearly, beautifully and modestly expressed. The title asks for a word to describe an attitude; the body makes clear that the word should apply to the attitude of all the participants

Comment: As Jim points out, it is not clear to whose behaviour you are referring. One word that may fit is _pharisee = 'a sanctimonious, self-righteous, or hypocritical person_' (Collins)

Comment: I'd describe the student president's address as ***trite***, and the entire context ***platitudinous***. But it's all a matter of opinions here.

Comment: I'm taking about both the president and the administrators. The point isn't that the talking points are trite, but that they're trite yet considered awe-inspiring. It's self-serving, self-righteous, and self-satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

This situation is known as **virtue signaling** or **grandstanding**

The speaker is moralistically **smug**, **piously** self-assured, and **self-righteous**.

The administrators are complacent like someone else said, but they're also:

- **mannered** (because they're externalizing and faking a certain kind of politically-correct image)
- **disingenuous** (because they actually don't give a shit), and
- **pretentious** (because they not only feign being impressed by the speech, but they also pretend that they've accomplished a lot when in reality they've done nothing)

You could call their response **contrived**.

---

**smug/pious**: having a holier-than-thou moralizing rhetoric or countenance

> (smug) "having or showing an excessive pride in oneself or one's achievements" (Oxford)

> (pious) "making a hypocritical display of virtue" (Oxford)

> (self-righteous) "characterized by a certainty, especially an unfounded one, that one is morally superior" (Oxford)

**mannered**: over elaborately and artificially delivered in manner

> "having an artificial character" (Merriam)

Answer (score 0):

All are *complacent* in their attitudes.

> = marked by self-satisfaction especially when accompanied by unawareness of actual dangers or deficiencies : marked by complacency : self satisfied.
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complacent)

> = feeling so satisfied with your own abilities or situation that you feel you do not need to try any harder
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/complacent)

The president is complacent because she feels good about her words and their reception but does not recognise the deficiency or incongruity that she has been entertained by the system she claims to be disrespectful. The doe-eyed are complacent because they agree but do nothing.

All feel they have done enough. None feel the need to try harder.

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm going for, but it's close. The point isn't that they're complacent, it's that their *egos* are puffed up but something *vacuous* and *ridiculous*.

Comment: It is clear what you are looking for, despite the closers who want more detail or clarity.  It may not be possible to find one word to do the job. I couldn’t. Surely there is something to combine the necessary elements of complacency, conceit, self-importance and inflated ego? I considered that the whole episode might be a *wind-egg*, but that does not help in describing the *attitude* of the participants.